# How much data can a websocket consumer handle?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I've built a simple application using Django Channels where a Consumer receives data from an external service, the consumer than sends this data to some subscribers on another consumer.
I'm new to websockets and i had a little concern: the consumer is receiving a lot of data, in the order of 100 (or more) JSON records per second. At what point should i be worried about this service crashing or running into performance issues? Is there some sort of limit for what i'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is not explicit limit, however it is worth nothing that for each instances (open connection) of the consumer you can only process one WS message at once.

So if you have a single websocket connection and are sending lots and lots of WS messages down that connection if the consumer does work on these (eg write them to the db) the queue of messages might fill up and you will get an error.

their are a few solutions to this,

1. Open multiple ws connections and share out the load
2. in your consumer before doing any work that will take time put it onto a `work queue` and have some background tasks (that you do not await) consume it.

For this second option it is probably a good idea to create this background queue in your `on_connect` method and handle shutting it down/waiting for it to flush everything in the on disconnect method.

--

if you are expecting a massive amount of data and don't want to fork out for a costly (high memory) VM you might be better of using a server that is no written in python.

My suggestion for a python developer would be https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/websockets/ this is a Swift server framework, Swift linguistically if very close to TypeAnotated python so is easier than other high performance options to pick up for a python dev.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I made various tests locally, and it handled 100/200 json records per second with no problems; under the hood it's using Redis. I think i already did what you suggest in poin 2) by setting the expiry date to 2 seconds, i've never had the queue full until now. I still do not know if the amount will be massive since i'm new to this, so i don't know what is the general consensus for 'massive'

Comment: so there are 2 things that might happen: 1) the queue of messages might build up (this depends on how long it takes for you to work on them). 2) the memory usage might go up. (this is also related to how large the queue gets but also related to how large the message is and how many open connections you have and how much mem each message uses). In then end channels keeps of of the messages in memory so if your queue depth 10 and you have 100MB per message and 10 connections then thats at min 10GB. this will cost a lot.

Comment: Consider that for message i mean a JSON dict of about 4/5 keys. I set the capacity of my queue to 1500 messages with an expiry of 2 seconds, i can lower it to 1 second, i will see if that will be enough to empty the queue; splitting the load across different consumers is another option and i'm already doing it!